# If one of eyes is blind, can that eye still feel pain?

Tags: eyes, human-eye

I was wondering this when I touched my bare eye (my eye was open) and since I'm not blind I was wondering if an eye is blind, can it still feel pain?

Answer (score 9):

Blindness can be due to a damage of the lens, retina, *optic nerve* or the visual area at the occipital lobe of the brain, for example.

Sensitivity of the eye cornea is enabled by a different nerve - the *ophthalmic nerve,* which is a branch of the trigeminal nerve ([Yale Journal of Biology and Medicine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5872636/)). As long as this nerve, somatosensory cortex at the parietal lobe of the brain and other neural structures involved in pain sensation are intact, you should be able to feel pain when touching the cornea of the blind eye.